Apache POI read Word，then throw UnsupportedZipFeatureException：Unsupported feature data descriptor used in entry word/media/image2.jpeg
I try to parse the document with XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
the while error is that:
java
org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.UnsupportedZipFeatureException: Unsupported feature data descriptor used in entry word/media/image2.jpeg
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.read(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:447)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.read(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:80)
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:182)
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:149)
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveFakeEntry.<init>(ZipArchiveFakeEntry.java:47)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:53)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:106)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:307)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:47)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:142)

I know the root reason is about ZipArchiveInputStream, it do work when i use new ZipArchiveInputStream(inputStream, CharsetUtil.defaultCharset().name(),false, true),
but in XWPFDocuments constructor method, it use ZipArchiveInputStreams default constructor, arg allowStoredEntriesWithDataDescriptor is default false.
How can i deal with XWPFDocument about this problem to parse document correctly

POI is open source code. You can copy it and modify it. The POI code can eventually be changed but it could be months until there is a new release.

I raised https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68987
